# Providing an Export Compliance Documentation Document for HTTPS / API calls required for Apps use outside the USA?

Tags: app-store-connect

Is an Export Compliance Document required for the use of HTTPS API calls if you plan to submit your app to countries outside the US?

How should this Export Compliance Document look like? What are the codes one should use?
Has anyone done this before?

Here is the example sheet from the US government website.

[image]

Comment: This is a legal question, not a programming question, hence it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes you are right, but everyone who wants to develope & deploy a iOS APP which makes https calls wants to know how to do this correctly.

Comment: Yes i know its a legal issue, but programmers have probably been asked this before? Also it relates to whether one can flag it as exempt or not. Or provide an annual cert. I have emailed BIS and the NSA. lets see if they reply. i will post the answer then.